# custom permission can't sign contract 309005

Tags: permissions

Using this permission:

```
increment(){
/* code

*/  
   require_auth(permission_level{_self, inc});
}
```

for an account that has the following permissions 
permissions:

```
 owner: EOS...
       active: EOS..., alice@active, ...
       inc: bob@active
```

I'm unable to sign this contract with the command (contract is set to alice account, action to execute is increment)

```
 cleos push action alice increment '""' -p alice@inc
```

or

```
 cleos push action alice increment '""' -p bob@active
```

And I'm getting error message

```
 309005: ... minimum authority is active.
```

How to get around this, so that I can use my custom permission? I've tried several versions, but never been able to sign a contract. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because **_self** is **alice**, your two push actions are not executed.

If you set **inc** to **alice@active**, **cleos push action alice increment '""' -p alice@inc** will be executed.